# Return value from getBulkProperties Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I'd like to return the data from the `viewer.model.getBulkProperties2` success callback like this

```
  getOmniValues(){
       return this.viewer.model.getBulkProperties2([],{propFilter:["OmniClass_21_Numero"]},(val)=>val)
  }
```

but I think the function returns void. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [getBulkProperties2](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getbulkproperties2-dbids-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method and many other viewer methods are [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous), meaning that they cannot return the result immediately as they typically need to wait for another async operation such as a web request or a long-running task on another thread. That's why you typically need to provide a callback function that's called later when the web request or long-running task finishes.

If you want to avoid the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com), you can wrap the method in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and then use the more modern `async/await` JavaScript:

```js
function getProps(model, dbids, options) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        model.getBulkProperties2(dbids, options, resolve, reject);
    });
}

// Note the `async` keyword below which is required if we want to `await` something inside the function
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, async function (ev) {
    const props = await getProps(viewer.model, [123, 456]);
    console.log(props);
});
```

Comment: That's actually perfect. Thank you @Petr !

Comment: @petr-broz I believe that the current version accepts a callback function for both onSuccess and onError.